# Is it worth it to buy SSD drives to a Synology DS218+ for home use?

Tags: ssd, nas

I am going to purchase a Synology DiskStation 218+ for home usage. Now, this will be physically located in my apartment and I am fearing that the rattle of two SATA HDD will be disturbing.

The NAS will not be used constantly, but only from time to time as of the situation is right now. I think I think the required diskspace will be about 2 TB (RAID1). So looking at the compatibility list on Synologys website, the SSD drives there are quite expensive (2TB drives goes for about 450-900 USD, tax included converted from SEK). This sounds quite expensive and I am not sure if my nights sleep is worth this much.

So now I am wondering two things:

- Is it possible to buy SSD drives that not is on the compatibility list?
- Does anyone have an opinion on the sound, is having regular 3.5" SATA going to be annoying or is it possible to live with this noise, unless I want to spend 1000-2000 USD on buying SSD drives?

BR
Patrik

Comment: The sound of drives isn't really noticeable unless significant disk activity is going on. Is that going to be the case with your machine while you are sleeping? Also, why is SSD compatibility an issue? I thought all SSD were pretty much the same.

Comment: According to what I've read, 5400 rpm 3.5" HDDs should emit only a quiet murmur. 7200 rpm drives are clearly audible and I'm saying this from experience. If you're worried about performance, then look at benchmarks before buying. AFAIR 5400 rpm 3 TB drives have read/write speeds sufficient to handle saturated 1Gbit Ethernet.

Comment: Thanks @gronostaj Thanks for the comment. This and the answer to me convinced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal experience is based on WD EX4 with 4 WD 7200rpm 4TB disks in RAID5. Yes, there is noise. Especially when I run some task on the NAS itself (downloading, extracting huge archive, export a lot of images, copy huge amount of information). But even with such noise I have no problem to sleep in the next room (with open door between the rooms). Of course the sensitivity to such noise is something very personal, but my opinion is it's not a problem.

BTW enterprise grade HDD are much more noisy (they are created for reliability) and I will not advise to add such disks in home NAS.